# How to use LocalAlloc and LocalReAlloc correctly

Tags: c++, winapi

I am going to learn how to use `LocalAlloc` and also `LocalReAlloc` of the Win32 API. I written the following code, but it gives me exceptions. I don't know what is wrong with the following code.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace code
{
    namespace memory
    {
        void allocation()
        {
            char* string = reinterpret_cast<char*>(LocalAlloc(LPTR, 6 + 1));
            CopyMemory(string, "WINAPI", 6);
            std::printf("%s\n", string);


            string = reinterpret_cast<char*>(LocalReAlloc(string, 6 + 13 + 1, LMEM_MOVEABLE));
            CopyMemory(string + 6, "IS THE BEST", 13);
            std::printf("%s\n", string);

            delete string;
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    code::memory::allocation();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above program, it doesn't give me any error but when I run it, it gives me the exception. The following message is from the exception:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...Windows\00 Windows API Programming\Debug\52_DynamicMemory.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 904

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Free the memory with `LocalFree` not `delete` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

A complete lack of error handling.

If `LocalReAlloc()` fails, you are leaking the memory allocated by `LocalAlloc()`.

The second `CopyMemory()` is exceeding the bounds of the string literal being copied. And you are not ensuring the reallocated memory is null terminated for the following `printf()`, were the literal being copied properly.

You are not freeing the allocated memory correctly. You must use `LocalFree()`, not `delete`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

namespace code
{
    namespace memory
    {
        void allocation()
        {
            char* string = static_cast<char*>(LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, 6 + 1));
            if (!string) return;

            std::strcpy(string, "WINAPI");
            std::printf("%s\n", string);

            char* newstring = static_cast<char*>(LocalReAlloc(string, 6 + 12 + 1, LMEM_MOVABLE));
            if (!newstring) { LocalFree(string); return; }
            string = newstring;

            std::strcpy(string + 6, " IS THE BEST");
            std::printf("%s\n", string);

            LocalFree(string);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    code::memory::allocation();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`LocalAlloc` Allocates the specified number of bytes from the heap, and if fails, returns value is `NULL`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.
If the `LocalAlloc` function succeeds, allocates at least the amount requested, and to free allocated memory call `LocalFree`

`LocalReAlloc` used to re-alloceate memory that allocated either by `LocalAlloc` or  `LocalReAlloc`, note that if `LocalReAlloc` fails, the original memory **is not freed**, and the original handle and pointer are still valid.